# ¿Cómo enviar un dato cada segundo por un emitter nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Resulta que mi código lee los datos de un txt linea a linea, y después de eso los envió por un emitter a otro archivo, sucede que el código ha recibido muchos datos del txt, pero yo no necesito todos eso valores que estoy recibiendo, entonces lo que necesito es enviar un valor de esos por un emitter, pero enviarlo cada segundo ignorando el resto que han llegado.

acá esta el código:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

readFile.on('line', function (line) {
    element = line.split('\t');
    var counter = 0;
        for(let property of element){
            counter++;
            console.log("1",counter, property)
            if(counter === 7){
                convertNumber = parseFloat(property);
                console.log("2", counter, convertNumber, property)
                myEmitter.emit('event', convertNumber)
                counter = 0;
            }

        }
})
```

intente con un setTimeOut pero enviaba siempre el mismo valor.